# How can I determine whether a SSD is compatible in my Dell?

Tags: ssd, dell-dimension

I have a Dell Inspiron 530 desktop with a manufacture date of 2008 August 12.

It's a quad core 2 with windows vista. Anyway I want to add a SSD to it.

How do I know what SSD is compatible with my machine?

[This](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820139133) looks interesting to me, but how do I know if it's compatible? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its the OS to worry about, W7 is optimized for SSD, in Vista and XP you have to do some tweaking after the OS is installed, like partition alignment, disable disk defragmentation, etc . It should work fine in your Dell. Do lots of reading. Install the OS clean when using a SSD drive.

See this article

http://lifehacker.com/5586733/how-to-take-full-advantage-of-your-solid+state-drive

Also
http://www.kingston.com/support/ssdnow/faq/default.asp?s=SNV425-S2BD

Comment: What about SATA III? Could I get one of those?

Comment: Yes. Should be no problem